# PHP ImageMagick returning incorrect content types

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have an [image generator](https://github.com/deidee/delogo/blob/3b44d235e08a208aa66764f225a32b00149b5ad7/src/class.delogo.php) that allows me to generate different file formats (like JPEG, PNG, etc.) on the fly using [`Imagick::setImageType`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagetype.php). This works like a charm on my old laptop *and* on a production server, but on a newer laptop that I started using, [`Imagick::getImageMimeType`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagemimetype.php) appears to not know what the correct MIME types for common image formats are, and returns `image/x-png` for PNG, `image/x-gif` for GIF, etc.

What’s curious to me, is that the content of the images that are generated (by echoing [`Imagick::getImageBlob`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageblob.php)) look just fine, which implies *ImageMagick* itself is working correctly. The only problem is that it sends these incorrect content type headers, which cause webbrowsers to download the image, rather than display it (except for the case of `image/x-png`, which browser happen to recognize as a legacy MIME type).

The only differencs with the other laptop I can think of is that this one is using newer software (PHP 7.4 on Windows 10 versus PHP 7.2 on Windows 7), but I fail to see how that would have anything to do with the mapping from image types to content types in *ImageMagick*.

Frankly, I have no idea where to start looking (googling didn’t help me much in this case), and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

For what it’s worth, this is the relevant section from `phpinfo()` in the environment where it’s acting weird:

| imagick module | enabled |
| --- | --- |
| imagick module version | 3.4.4 |
| imagick classes | Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel |
| Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version | ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x64 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org |
| Imagick using ImageMagick library version | ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x64 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org |
| ImageMagick copyright | Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC |
| ImageMagick release date | 2017-11-23 |
| ImageMagick number of supported formats: | 238 |
| ImageMagick supported formats | 3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CLIPBOARD, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPS, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EMF, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FILE, FITS, FLIF, FPX, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, GV, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JP2, JPC, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPM, JPS, JPT, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCREENSHOT, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBP, WMF, WMV, WPG, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out some random things, I found something that surprisingly works in this case. I installed the plain old [ImageMagick Windows installer](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), and *removed* all the DLL mumbo-jumbo that all the online tutorials talk about (except for the `php_imagick.dll` in `php/ext`, of course).

So my setup is a lot simpler than it was before, and works better.